# PHP onchange event of select box

Tags: php, onchange

I am new to PHP and this community
I was trying to use onchange function in php select
but it seems to be not working
I searched for solutions but basically are all with JS and the value goes to the URL, but my value is going to use in php for loop
don't want to get the parameter in URL
please help

```
echo "<select onchange='myFunction(this.value)'>";
echo "<option value=''>select your number</option>";
echo "<option value='5'>5</option>";
echo "<option value='10'>10</option>";
echo "<option value='15'>15</option>";
echo "</select>";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function myFunction($numbers){
    for($count=0;$count<$numbers;$count++)
        echo $count;
}
```

by the way, inside for loop contains some MySQL so that's why i'm using PHP

Comment: onchange method is for javascript the client script not for php the server script.

Comment: Learn the basic concept before implementing and posting question on stack

Comment: then how may i get the value from JS to php?

Comment: You want to mix PHP with Javascript but they never mix. The PHP is interpreted on the server, it generates a page (HTML+CSS+JS or something else) that is sent back to the browser. The HTML and the Javascript code (if any) are interpreted by the browser. The Javascript code runs in a different context, on a different computer, at a different moment in time (after the PHP code completes).

Comment: don't know who is upvoting this kind of questions?

Answer (score 1):

```js
         function change_function(element){
     document.location.href = element.value
 
      }
```

```html
        <select class="form-contro-drop" name="val"  onChange="change_function(this);" >
    <option value="ur.php?val=1">1</option> <option value="ur.php?val=2">2</option></select>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can coding like this

```js
<?php 
header('contact-type:text/javascript;charset=utf-8');
echo "<select onchange='myFunction(this.value)'>";
echo "<option value=''>select your number</option>";
echo "<option value='5'>5</option>";
echo "<option value='10'>10</option>";
echo "<option value='15'>15</option>";
echo "</select>";
?>
<script>
function myFunction($numbers){
    for($count=0;$count<$numbers;$count++)
        echo $count;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `echo` is a PHP statement, there is no `echo` in Javascript.

Comment: The header `contact-type:` doesn't exist. If you generate custom headers their names must start with `X-` and there should be code at the other side (client code) that can read and interpret them. You probably meant `Content-Type:`.